# Get configuration of running sshd

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is it possible to get a list of all the currently active configuration options of a running sshd task? Something like connecting, using a command via ssh and then disconnect?

I know I can read the configuration file and derive from there but:

- There are options with defaults which are not explicitely set in the sshd_config
- Finding the correct config file is not always easy (as it can be changed)
- There are commandline options overriding sshd_config
- ... ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have control over the sshd?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to dump the configuration from running `sshd`, but you can instruct the `sshd` to parse the configuration and dump the resulting applied configuration options including default values from the default configuration file. There is `-T` switch for that:

```
sshd -T
```

Note: You can have commandline options overriding sshd_config.

You can use `-f` switch to read the configuration file from different file.

Everything is well documented in manual page for `sshd`.

Comment: The -T switch is what I need, thank you for that.

Comment: @Paxsali this question is about sshd, which has the `-f` for the config file though.